# Deploying metadata in non devhub sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx

What is the best way to deploy metadata into non devhub sandbox using salesforce dx ?

As i cannot use packaging in non devhub sandbox need some help?

Answer (score 3):

You have two options.

- You can use the [pre-release version](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/wiki/Develop-Against-Any-Org-in-Visual-Studio-Code) of Salesforce DX, which supports development against sandboxes. This is most applicable if you want to continue development using a sandbox as backing, rather than doing a one-time deployment.
- You can use the `force:source:convert` command to generate Metadata API source from your SFDX project. Then, use the `force:mdapi:deploy` command to deploy the MD API source package to your target sandbox. This is most applicable if you want to do a one-time deployment to the sandbox, but plan to continue developing against your scratch orgs.